# can an iframe set up the session storage on the host Page

Tags: iframe

I have an iFrame showing up in my react app, which is hosting an iframe to show another app in an iframe. we are passing some bootstrapping info to the iframe like the data it should show when it launches. interestingly when the iframe launches, I see a new domain show up in the Session Storage of chrome and some key-value pairs are in it.

Is it possible for the iframe we are launching to store it in the SessionStorage of the hosting app? I couldn't find any session setting code on our app when we launch the iframe. How do I confirm that?
we are using sandbox attribute for iframe with below values
`<iframe allowFullScreen sandbox=allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-scripts allow-same-origin.../>`
I am totally not sure if both page & iframe belong to same domain as URLs are very similar but couldn't conclude
eg: mysite URL: `abcd.efgh.myorg.com`
iframe URL: `xyz.efgh.myorg.com`

P.S: I am new to this app and we don't have access to the app code that the iframe shows.

Answer (score 2):

The read-only ‍`sessionStorage‍‍` property accesses a session [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) object for the current [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin).

Theoretically, you can access the session storage of the host page if the origin test passes. you can also test simply if you have access to the iframe element. Remove the `src` attribute and replace it with `srcdoc`.

```
<iframe 
  srcdoc="<script>sessionStorage.setItem('__key__', '__value__')</script>" 
/>
```

Base on [Scripting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#scripting) section in the doc

> From the inside of a frame, a script can get a reference to its parent window with `window.parent`. Script access to a frame's content is subject to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Scripts cannot access most properties in other window objects if the script was loaded from a **different origin**, including scripts inside a frame accessing the frame's parent. Cross-origin communication can be achieved using [`Window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

#### Wrap up

- If you have the iframe with a same-origin policy, you can directly change Session storage.
- otherwise, you must implement a mechanism for postMessage mechanism to subscribe to a certain event (dispatched from your iframe)

  - receive and store data on your host page
  - share data with iframe